# Are there standard guidelines on apostrophising to denote swallowed syllables for scansion?

Tags: poetry, meter, orthography

There are various words in English which can be pronounced in different ways with different numbers of syllables. Poetry often requires them to be read in a particular way for appropriate scansion, which has led to practices such as putting an accent on a syllable that *should* be pronounced but might not always be, or apostrophising out a syllable that *shouldn't* be pronounced but often might be: for example, "wand'ring" or "gath'ring" to indicate that these words should be bisyllabic.

I'm currently writing a poem in which I want "traditional" to be trisyllabic, but I'm struggling to indicate this in writing in a way that looks natural: "tradit'nal" and "traditi'nal" make it look like the second "t" should be hard, and "tradish'nal" doesn't look suitable for the style of, well, traditional poetry. I mention the above as motivation for my question, which isn't about writing but rather about existing poetry: **are there any guidelines or standards on how apostrophes are used in poetry to indicate swallowed syllables?** Certainly using them in this way is a thing I've seen done a lot, but I don't know if it's done according to any rules or just poetic licence.

Comment: Just write it and let the reader figure the pronunciation out. I don’t think there’s any other choice.